# Anonymous user enter the app without token and anonymous user want to login then i need to send token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, retrofit, bearer-token

what I do in this=> if DO_IT_LATER value ==1 then i am not sending token else sending token
but the problem is that I entered the application with the anonymous user now DO_IT_LATER value is 1 and I'm not sending the token after the anonymous user wants to log in and the user goes to the login page then I assign the DO_IT_LATER value is 0 if the user clicks to login button I want to send the token

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object RetrofitModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideBaseUrl() = BuildConfig.BASE_URL

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideHttpLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor =
        HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideNetworkConnectionMonitor(@ApplicationContext context: Context): NetworkConnectionMonitor =
        AndroidNetworkConnectionMonitor(context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager)

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideAuthorizationToken(@ApplicationContext context: Context): TokenInterceptor =
        TokenInterceptor(context)

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideInterceptorHeader(): InterceptorHeader =
        InterceptorHeader()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideOkHttpClient(
        httpLoggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor,
        networkConnectionMonitorInterceptor: NetworkConnectionMonitorInterceptor,
        interceptorHeader: InterceptorHeader,
        authToken: TokenInterceptor
//    ) = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    ) = if (AppConstants.DO_IT_LATER == 1) {
  OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptorHeader)
            .addNetworkInterceptor(networkConnectionMonitorInterceptor)
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()
    
 Log.d("Retrofit", "anonymous")
       
    } else {
           Log.d("Retrofit", "Normal")
      
 httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
        OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
            .addInterceptor(interceptorHeader)
            .addInterceptor(authToken)
            .addNetworkInterceptor(networkConnectionMonitorInterceptor)
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(
        okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
        BASE_URL: String
    ): Retrofit =
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApiService(retrofit: Retrofit): com.myapp.di.ApiService =
        retrofit.create(com.myapp.di.ApiService::class.java)
}
```